# Learning to connect R to SQL database

Tags: sql, r, dbi

I am just learning how to use R to connect to SQL database. When I run my code, I am getting a message box says:

```
library(odbc)
con <- dbConnect(odbc(),Driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Serve",
                 Server ="DESKTOP-SHXXX",
                 Database ="BikeStores",
                 UID="robin",
                 PWD = rstudioapi::askForPassword("xxx"),
                 Trusted_Connection ="yes")
# Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 08001: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL 
# Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].
# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired  
# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-
# specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. 
# Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct 
# and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more 
# information see SQL Server Books Online.
```

Any help?

Comment: Your `"Driver="` doesn't look like a driver to me, it more looks like your local hostname; I'd expect something like `"ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"` or `"PostgreSQL ANSI(x64)"`. Do you see that in `odbc::odbcListDrivers()[,"name"]`? Also, are you running the SQL Server on the same machine as RStudio?

Comment: @r2evans:   Driver= is my sever name. I shortened it for security reason. DESKTOP-SHXXX\SQLEXPRESS that's the full name. I don't see it in odbc::odbcListDrivers()[,"name"]. yes, I am running the SQL on the desktop as Rstudio.

Comment: con <- dbConnect(odbc(),Driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
                 Server ="DESKTOP-SHXXX",
                 Database ="BikeStores",
                 UID="robin",
                 PWD = rstudioapi::askForPassword("xxx"),
                 Trusted_Connection ="yes")

Comment: this is what i got: Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 08001: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.

Comment: Not sure. Please [edit] your question and add this updated code and the error text (comments can easily be skipped by readers or hidden by the interface). Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is it a typo that you defined `Driver="ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Serve"` without the trailing "r"? The "cannot connect" error could be for many reasons, including many unrelated to R. If you have installed if via docker, then make sure you are including `docker run -p "1433:1433"` on the command line. If you are running it natively, make sure you don't have a firewall disabling it.

Comment: Have you fixed the issue yet? FYI, I'm running sql server locally and can connect using `dbConnect(drv = odbc::odbc(), driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server", server = "127.0.0.1", database = "master", uid = "SA", pwd = "Mysecretpassword1")`. The differences I see: `"Server"` (including the last `"r"`), `"127.0.0.1"` instead of your local hostname; and I'm not using `"Trusted_Connection"`.

Comment: I fixed it already. thanks! I think the issue was to create the ODBC data source on pc.

Comment: FYI, I don't use named data sources (win10 and linux); they're convenient for some things but not required. Glad you are able to connect now.